# How to use a multiset? (guava)

Tags: guava, multiset

Is it possible to use a Multiset for the purpose of counting letter frequencies of the first letter in a word. Those words exist in a list.

example. [the, quick, brown, fox, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog]

**Output:** most common first character: [t, q, b, f, j, o, l, d]

**Output:** Most common first character ignoring word frequency: [t]

I just started researching how to  use guava solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You'd just need to create a `Multiset<Character>`, then iterate over the words and add their first character to your multiset (note: there are i18n issues with this, as a general thing). You could either keep track of the most common character as you go or iterate over the multiset later to get it.